How do I add data to a specific firestore database
I have two firestore database in my firebase project. How do I add data to a specific database.

If you have two firestore database in single Firebase project , then you can  use below code:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final FirebaseApp firebaseApp=await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.web,
  );

FirebaseFirestore firestore=FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: firebaseApp,databaseURL: '(default)');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

This database url is your database name, for default database we pass (default), if you have 2 firestore database, one name will be (default) and other name might be something different. When initializing firestore instance just pass the database name.
